# Issues with Login form

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a login form in django. When I am running the app and filled the username and password fields. The page always redirected to one condition (whether the username is right or not).

The code is as :

```
def home(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST.get('user_name')
      password = request.POST.get('password')
      user = authenticate(user_name=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
        # success
           return render_to_response('registration/main_page.html',{'form':login},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
         #user was not active
           return render_to_response('registration/q.html')
      else:
        # not a valid user
           return render_to_response('registration/home.html')

   else:
       # URL was accessed directly
           return render_to_response('registration/w.html')
```

It always redirected to home.html

```
else:
             #user was not active
              return render_to_response('registration/home.html')
```

Why it happens?

Comment: you need to evaluate is_active for starters, it's not a template so it should be, user.is_active()

Comment: Your code examples are mixed up. The comment says #user was not active but you are redirecting to the home page. Looking at the top code, the redirect to the home page is done when the user isn't valid. Which case is correct?

Comment: I guess the user that is passed here is inactive

Comment: Also is_active is a Boolean property so no need for paranthesis

Comment: you don't have a variable `'login'` so when a user does enter the correct credentials you'll get an error on this `{'form':login}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate()` function takes `username` not `user_name`.

Try this: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

Also, instead of `if user is not None:` you can write `if user :`

Comment: If that isn't a typo, there's your problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

It seems your function returns a None object here:

```
if user is not None
```

You can add print statements to pin it down,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST.get('user_name')
      password = request.POST.get('password')

      print username # what does it return?

      user = authenticate(user_name=username, password=password)

      print user # what does it return?

      if user is not None:
          #...
```